# Should I explicitly =delete non-const rvalue ref qualified function?

Tags: c++, lvalue-to-rvalue

I have a class `A` that has a non-const member function `foo` that must not be called on temporaries, this is how it looks like:

```
struct A
{
    void foo() &
    {...}
};
```

If `foo` were `const` I would have to explicitly delete the `const&&` version since const rvalues can bind to const lvalues, in fact the following code compiles just fine

```
struct A
{
    void const_foo() const &
    {...}

    // void const_foo() const&& = delete;
    // ^^^^ uncomment to prevent calling foo on const rvalues
};

int main()
{
    const A a;
    std::move(a).const_foo();
}
```

So there's a reason to explicitly delete a const rvalue ref qualified function, are there any reasons also for non-const functions?

Comment: What exactly is the reason your `foo()` should not be called on temporaries?

Comment: I can’t think of an actual reason, but I would =delete it in any case to make your intent clear.

Comment: @G. Sliepen In my case `foo` does some heavy modifications on internal data members and does not have any side effect, thus calling it on a temporary makes no sense since the object is going to die anyway. A good compiler may optimize out the call but may not warn me. By deleting it instead, the code won't compile and I would understand I'm doing something wrong